# PHP preg_replace() vs filter_var()

Tags: php, security

I have seen numerous posts on this subject but none really answered my questions.

I have some user input that is inserted into my DB and displayed back to the user later. Before inserting it into the DB I validate the input. When I need to display it back to the user I have been using two different methods.

The first is using `preg_replace()`. With this I can do things like remove all non alphanumeric characters. The second method is to use `filter_var()` with an option like `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`, which will strip tags and encode special characters.

What I havent been able to find is which I *should* be using and of course, why.

Comment: Why should you use any of them? What are you trying to accomplish? What are you trying to protect your app against?

Comment: @VincentSavard In the event something gets past my validation, there is another layer of security when it is displayed back to a user later.

Comment: Seems fairly well-answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Answer (score 0):

> The first is using preg_replace()

I think preg_replace is more safer and have high performance for it.

> filter_var()

I think if you use it you don't know some results because of you don't know how it works and it affects the performance of your application

Answer (score 0):

*Given PHP, I'm assuming this is for a web application. As opposed of using PHP from terminal or doing a desktop application with PHP (yes, that is possible).*

---

### Validation

First of all, yes, you validate on input and sanitize on output. You must validate against your model/domain/business logic. Because text does not make sense in a numeric field, and so on.

Validate twice. Once on the client, which provides better user experience by giving faster and contextual feedback, it also means less network traffic (so input errors do not cost data to the or congestion to the server). And once on the server, because the user is in control of the client, all validation on the client can be bypassed. You could have a modified client, request forgery or similar.

And for that use [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is often OK. However, Just using `filter_var` does not give you the client side validation code. This means you have to duplicate the effort on the client, I'd say look into using a validation library that can do that.

We want to have a single source of truth about how a field is validated... otherwise we could end up with discrepancies between how the client validates and how the server validates.

On that note, remember that client side validation is for convenience. Thus, if they are going to differ, let the client be permissive and the server strict.

---

If validation failed on the client. JavaScript can show contextual help based on whatever validation information it has.

If it fails on the server... Well, first of all, you should have a custom header to tell the server if the request comes from JavaScript (You know, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), ajax and so on). Now, if this request does not come from JavaScript, you store some error information as a session variable (issuing a cookie if appropriate), redirect back to the form, where you show custom error message based on the error information. *See also [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).* If it comes from JavaScript, return an HTTP error status with the error information, and JavaScript can deal with showing the custom error message.

---

### Sanitation

If only alphanumeric characters are valid (as a requirement of the application)... Validate, reject the input if it is not alphanumeric.

If you want to help the user, you can handle it on the client side. Use HTML + JavaScript to either allow only alphanumeric values (you can highlight contextual help if the user is trying to input something invalid), or failing that, remove all non-alphanumeric characters when the field loses focus (or the form is send). For user experience, if possible, we want the user to be aware of the transformation we are doing to the text.

No, we do not need to replicate that as a sanitation step on the server. The server can just reject the input.

---

On a related note, having an application that allows you to write `<script>alert("hello");</script>` on a text input/textarea/contenteditable div, without causing a JavaScript injection is valid. Oh, look, that did not run! And it did not strip `<` and `>`.

---

Instead, you sanitize on output. Depending on where you output. This sanitation should prefer escaping over stripping.

Remember that the way to escape is different depending on the target. If the data goes to an URL it is different if it goes to HTML (in the body, in an attribute value, in a CSS class name...), or to plain text, or perhaps it is part of a string in a JSON response, etc.

And for that use `filter_var` is sometimes OK. However, it is somewhat limited in sanitation options. You probably want to wrap it into your own solution, that for some targets it may use `filter_var` internally. And no, [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) is not the only alternative if you can decide in a case by case basis. You can use [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), [`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), etc.

*Did you know [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can do multiple replacements in one call? Yes, it can!*

*Did you know you can use a function to specify what you replace with if you use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback) instead? Yep, you can too.*

---

### Database

And use prepared statements. That is how you deal with SQL injection.

I understand that we can, and should, treat SQL as an I/O device, and thus sanitation makes sense when you output to the database... However, we want to be able to store any value on the database, which means stripping is bad idea. Plus using escape sequences is engine specific, and charset sensitive. Thus, I suggest to not sanitize when you write to the database, instead, please use prepared statements.

No, ORM and stored procedures are not a guarantee that SQL injection will not happen. *If you are writing an ORM solution, please use prepared statements internally.*

To reiterate, please use prepared statements.

---

On the idea that the database is an I/O device. It also makes sense to not trust comes from the database. Yet, let's be honest, this should not be a priority. The administrators who have access to the database to mess with it, they probably have access to the code too and do whatever they want... And if there is anyway an malicious third party can mess with the database, you have bigger problems.

Let us assume it is a concern anyway. Where does the information go? If you are going to just show it, then the sanitation for the particular output target will handle it.

That only leaves the case where you are going to operate on the data on the server *and you are paranoid.* And that is the only case where stripping based sanitation makes sense. *Stripping based sanitation is for the paranoid.*

---

### When to use regex

As I was saying in the sanitation part, you can choose in a case by case basis. With that said, as you would expect `preg_replace` is much more versatile than `filter_var`.

*Performance?*

In my experience it is not really a problem. I haven't measured, because it has not been a problem. Yet, if you want, you can easily test, use [`hrtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime) (or [`microtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) on older PHP). *Repeat the call a fixed number of times in a loop for a better measure.* It, of course, depends on the particular regex code you are throwing in.

Which brings me to: regex is harder to maintain. It is because of this many will encourage `filter_var`, as it is much harder to get wrong. Just because you can do regex does not mean you should use it for everything. *[Mandatory xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/208/).*

The flip side is that you can take advantage of the [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute in HTML, which takes a regex. *Make sure the regex is valid on both JavaScript and PHP.* And you got a single source of truth about how to validate the field. You can add a JavaScript library that looks at the input attributes and augments it with visual feedback (which will gracefully degradare to browser validation when JavaScript is disabled), you may even polyfill support for the `pattern` attribute (and other validation related features) in older browsers.

Thus, if you are building a PHP validation solution, my suggestion is to mimic what HTML does. And yes, that means supporting regex, but not always using regex.

As per sanitation, as I was saying, `filter_var` sanitation options are limited. So you would supplement it with other functions. Including, but not limited to, `preg_replace_callback` (which is what you want to do custom escape sequences).